# Send and receive double[][] in c# webservices error

Tags: c#, jquery, web-services

I want to receive and send matrix (double[][]) using a c# webservice RESTfull.

I tried diferent options but without any sucess.

C# code:

```
[HttpGet()]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]

    public justTest doSomething([FromUri] double[][] a)
    {
        justTest j = new justTest();

        return j;
    }
```

Javascript/Jquery:

```
var array = [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]];
var object = {
    a: array
}

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:53496/api/Operations/doSomething",
    data: object,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (x, e) {
        alert("ERRo")
    }
});
```

Error:

1. The c# paramenter a is null;
2. The c# sends the following error to the javascript:

   > An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"A referência de objecto não foi definida como uma instância de um objecto.","ExceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException","StackTrace":"

Thank you

Comment: You said you got an error, but never said what it was.

Comment: I will add the error that I receive

Comment: @Carcigenicate I edit the post to became more clear

Comment: Do you need to `stringify()` your `data` property in the AJAX call?

Comment: @DanWilson That was my next question. It's been awhile since I've made an AJAX request.

Comment: @DanWilson I don't think so beacuse if a pass a number instead of array and if in c# parameter I change it to a double instead of an array it works (for receive the parameters in c#). The same thing appenings if I send a double instead of a double[][] to the javascript.